# Keep v-tooltip open when hovering over the tooltip

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

First, the terms, "link" is the area where the mouse enters. The "tooltip" is the thing that pops up and shows extra information.
--- above added 2020-04-29

I'm using Vuetify and trying to keep the v-tooltip open when mouse is hovering over the "tooltip".
The content inside the tooltip is going to be rich and don't want that to automatically hide when visitor is looking into it.

```
<template>
<v-tooltip
  v-model="show"
  max-width="600px"
  content-class="link-tooltip-content"
  bottom>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <div
      :style="boxStyle"
      @mouseover="mouseover"
      @mouseleave="mouseleave"
    ></div>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:default>
    <v-card
      @mouseover="mouseover"
      @mouseleave="mouseleave"
      >
      <v-row dense>
        <v-col>
          <v-card-title class="headline">
            rich tooltip
          </v-card-title>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-card>
  </template>
</v-tooltip>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
  data: () => ({
    show: false,
    hoverTimer: null
  }),
  methods: {
    boxStyle: function() {
      return {
        left: "100px",
        top: "100px",
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px",
        position: "absolute"
      };
    },
    mouseover: function() {
      console.log(`mouseover`);
      this.show = true;
      clearTimeout(this.hoverTimer);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      console.log(`mouseleave`);
      this.hoverTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.show = false;
      }, 3000);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

But this doesn't work. The mouseover and mouseleave event handlers on the activator slot (the "link") element does fire, but the event handlers on the default slot (the "tooltip") don't fire.

I think the reason is, because the content inside the "tooltip" is moved to somewhere else under the body tag.

The questions is, how can I keep the "tooltip" open when hovering over it.

I'm moving the mouse like this:

1. Hover over the link (the tooltip shows up).
2. Move the mouse out of the link and into the tooltip. (The link and tooltip is a few pixels apart)
   Now the mouseleave event for the link fires, and I want to add a mouseenter event handler on the tooltip. **How do I do that ?**

I'm thinking to add an mouseenter event on the tooltip, so that I can `clearTimeout(hoverTimer)` and keep the tooltip open.

I know there's a similar question from 9 years ago, using jQuery [Keep tooltip opened when the mouse is over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933062/keep-tooltip-opened-when-the-mouse-is-over-it) , but I don't want to use jQuery if possible. I prefer a Vue way.

Here's a little reproducible example:
https://www.codeply.com/p/GuFXqAAU8Y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.v-tooltip__content` has `pointer-events:none` set in `vuetify.min.css`. If you set it back to `auto` you allow it to be hovered.

When its hovered, its parent is hovered. And when its parent is hovered, it has a tooltip. So all you need is:

```
.v-tooltip__content {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding about the problem. I edited the question. I think your answer makes sense when the tooltip is over the link, but it is not. In my case it's a few pixels apart.

Comment: @mash, I think your question needs a [mcve] reproducing the issue. UX problems can't really be soved by looking at code alone. You actually need a way to reproduce the UX in order to come up with improvements and also as a way to test any potential solution.

Comment: Updated the question and added an example!

Comment: @mash, I misread your question. You're asking the opposite of what I thought you were. Updated the answer to match your issue. Good thing I asked you to create a snippet.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `v-tooltip`, I suggest you use `v-menu` with the `open-on-hover` props set to `true`.
If you have to nudge whatever you put in the menu, make sure to set an appropriate `close-delay` value, so the menu doesn't close before the user reaches it.

Example:
https://codepen.io/stephane303/pen/WNwdNxY

```
    <v-menu open-on-hover right offset-x nudge-right="20" close-delay="100">
```

Answer (score 1):

I made extended version of VTooltip for this purpose. Just pass `interactive` prop. See working example here by hovering Governance stepper: https://tzkt.io

```
<script>
/**
 * Extends VTooltip with interactivity
 * @see https://material-ui.com/components/tooltips/#interactive
 */

import { VTooltip } from 'vuetify/lib';

export default {
    extends: VTooltip,
    props: {
        interactive: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        closeDelay: {
            type: [Number, String],
            default: 50,
        },
    },
    computed: {
        // I'm not 100% sure in this, but it works
        calculatedLeft() {
            const originalValue = VTooltip.options.computed.calculatedLeft.call(this);
            if (!this.interactive) return originalValue;
            const { left, right } = this;
            let value = parseInt(originalValue);
            if (left || right) {
                value += right ? -10 : 10;
            }
            return `${value}px`;
        },
        calculatedTop() {
            const originalValue = VTooltip.options.computed.calculatedTop.call(this);
            if (!this.interactive) return originalValue;
            const { top, bottom } = this;
            let value = parseInt(originalValue);
            if (top || bottom) {
                value += bottom ? -10 : 10;
            }
            return `${value}px`;
        },
        styles() {
            const originalValue = VTooltip.options.computed.styles.call(this);
            if (!this.interactive) return originalValue;
            const {
                top, bottom, left, right,
            } = this;
            let paddingDirection;
            if (bottom) paddingDirection = 'top';
            else if (top) paddingDirection = 'bottom';
            else if (right) paddingDirection = 'left';
            else if (left) paddingDirection = 'right';
            return {
                ...originalValue,
                [`padding-${paddingDirection}`]: `${10}px`,
            };
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onTooltipMouseenter(e) {
            if (this.interactive) {
                this.clearDelay();
                this.isActive = true;
            }
            this.$emit('tooltip:mouseenter', e);
        },
        onTooltipMouseleave(e) {
            if (this.interactive) {
                this.clearDelay();
                this.runDelay('close');
            }
            this.$emit('tooltip:mouseleave', e);
        },
        genContent() {
            const content = this.$createElement('div', this.setBackgroundColor(this.color, {
                style: this.contentStyles,
                staticClass: 'v-tooltip__content',
                class: {
                    [this.contentClass]: true,
                    menuable__content__active: this.isActive,
                },
            }), this.getContentSlot());
            return this.$createElement('div', {
                style: this.styles,
                attrs: this.getScopeIdAttrs(),
                class: {
                    'v-tooltip__wrapper': true,
                    'v-tooltip__wrapper--fixed': this.activatorFixed,
                },
                directives: [{
                    name: 'show',
                    value: this.isContentActive,
                }],
                on: {
                    mouseenter: this.onTooltipMouseenter,
                    mouseleave: this.onTooltipMouseleave,
                },
                ref: 'content',
            }, [content]);
        },
        genActivatorListeners() {
            const listeners = VTooltip.options.methods.genActivatorListeners.call(this);

            if (this.interactive) {
                if (listeners.mouseenter) {
                    listeners.mouseenter = (e) => {
                        this.getActivator(e);
                        this.clearDelay();
                        if (!this.isActive) {
                            this.runDelay('open');
                        }
                    };
                }
            }

            return listeners;
        },
    },

};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.v-tooltip__wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    &--fixed {
        position: fixed;
    }
    .v-tooltip__content {
        position: static;
    }
}
</style>
```